# AngularJs- Checkbox issue in safari

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, safari

I have a checkbox and dropdown. When I set checkbox to true and select an option from dropdown, checkbox clears itself.

In other browsers code is working fine but showing this strange behavior in safari.

```
    Below is my html and js:

    <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <span ng-repeat="bRelation in Relations|limitTo: 3">
                      <label class="checkbox" for="{{bRelation.Id}}">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="b-relation" ng-model="group" value="{{bRelation.Id}}" ng-change="checkRelation(bRelation.Id)" name="group" id="{{bRelation.Id}}" />
                          {{bRelation.Text}}
                          <select class="form-control brelationnum" name="brelationnum" style="display:inline;">
                            <option value="">-- Relatives Count --</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                          </select>
                      </label>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>

$scope.Relations = [
    {'Id' : '1', 'Text' : 'Grandmother' },
    {'Id' : '2', 'Text' : 'Mother' },
    {'Id' : '3', 'Text' : 'Sister' }
];
```

I have created a Pluker here: [Checkbox issue in safari](https://plnkr.co/edit/nlttcKuMfyL5D30HG0QC?p=preview)

Can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem is because of the `id` attribute of the checkbox, please remove the `id` since its causing the problem, also please use the `ng-model` as `bRelation.checked`, since it will easily track which checkbox is checked, please refer the below snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.details = [
   { "name": "Employees" },
   { "name": "Support" }
    ];
     $scope.details.name = [
   { "prof": "enginerr" },
   { "prof": "doctor" }
    ];
    $scope.Relations = [
    {'Id' : '1', 'Text' : 'Grandmother' },
    {'Id' : '2', 'Text' : 'Mother' },
    {'Id' : '3', 'Text' : 'Sister' }
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <span ng-repeat="bRelation in Relations|limitTo: 3">
                  <label class="checkbox" for="{{bRelation.Id}}">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="b-relation" ng-model="bRelation.checked" name="group"/>
                      {{bRelation.Text}}
                      <select class="form-control brelationnum" name="brelationnum" style="display:inline;">
                        <option value="">-- Relatives Count --</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                      </select>
                  </label>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <pre>{{Relations}}</pre>
            </div>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Ruchi Did this answer help you? or the problem still persists?

Comment: Pardon for the delay